# infinitive vs gerund usage

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, verbs, gerunds, infinitives

Is this sentence correct?

> "For me, in fact, it is really important to **knowing** people that may make you culturally richer"

Should it be  "important to know" or "important to knowing"?

What's the difference and why?

Comment: Thank you really much once again for your time and patience.
Are you completely sure about the " X is important to Y " part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence, as constructed, is not correct. "is important" would be followed by the infinite form of a verb. I can't find a definite reference on the Internet, but [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/important) has several examples of "is important to [infinitive verb]" format.

If you wanted to use gerund, you would typically use the form "[noun phrase] is important". So, your options are as follows:

> For me, in fact, it is really important to know people that may make you culturally richer.
>
> For me, in fact, knowing people that may make you culturally richer is really important.
>
> For me, in fact, to know people that may make you culturally richer is really important.

These are all sentences where we only refer to one thing (to know people) and say that it's important, i.e., "X (gerund/infinitive) is important" or "It is important to X (infinitive)". We are not specifying what X is important for.

On the other hand, if we look at the the sentence from the [OP's forum link](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic15277.html), it is of the form, "X is important to Y". In this case, you can use gerunds or noun phrases to describe both X and Y. For example:

> (Gerund) Good humidity, even moisture, and bright light are important to growing this species well.
>
> (Other noun phrase) Good humidity, even moisture, and bright light are important to the growth of this species.
>
> (Gerund for both X and Y) Having access to a lot of books is important to being a well-read person.

Contrast this with "It is important to X (infinitive)" form:

> It is important to have good humidity and moisture. (No information on what those are important to.)

Comment: Thank you really much.
Your answer seems to be good enough but I've read on a website I can still use that form , so I will wait for more clarification.
I hope you don't mind it .
Thanks again.

Comment: Could you share the website you read this on? The context might help.

Comment: Sure.
I don't know if it's " legal " to do this here , in case it's not , moderators will fix that , I guess.
Have a look here , no idea if that's reliable .
http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic15277.html

Comment: Edited my answer to cover the case from the forum link.

Comment: Thank you really much once again for your time and patience. Are you completely sure about the " X is important to Y " part?

Comment: I am certain of that use. Unfortunately, I can't find good examples from published content to back my claim here.